# On what level in the django MTV architecture does the Django Rest Framework work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I understand that django is an MTV architecture. I also understand that M is models, T is templates (which are views in MVC) and V is views (which are controllers in MVC).
I want to understand if the django serializers and views are views or templates according to the MTV when using Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect 1:1 mapping there.

A DRF serializer is vaguely like a template in that it describes how the data should be serialized "onto the wire" when a DRF view outputs it, but unlike templates, serializers can also be used for data ingestion.

DRF views (and viewsets, which group views) map to MVC controllers or Django views in that they describe how the API endpoint works.

A DRF app doesn't necessarily need to work with Django models at all, but if it does, that bit is unchanged from how Django works.